# How to improve maintainability and testability of a service by refactoring it into a functional style

Tags: c#, unit-testing, functional-programming

A customer of ours has a rather large (500+ LOC) service as central part of the project. Written in C# and consisting of rather clunky large imperative style functions, I was asked to improve the test coverage.

After trying for some time to do so without touching the underlying code, I quickly found, that the result would be extremely brittle, and much to close to the code, to be really anything else than a fig-leaf.

So I proposed a refactoring of the service into a more functional approach, thereby improving both the testability and maintainability of the code.

What I did was to separate the code into three layers.

The outer layer was to preserve the basic signature of the old functions, as to not having to make any changes to other components of the project. In essence all I do in the public async methods here, is handing the external params as well as partially applied external functions (sometimes even reduced to mere Tasks) down into the middle layer. Given that I prepare all the external stuff here I can easily mock those in the tests for the middle layer. So in essence: "map unproven externals to be used in pure functions, and thereby expose the functionality of the service to the outside world".

The middle layer consists of the internal flow of the functions, basically translating the former "if a go on, else return with error" to a "funcA.bind(funcB).bind(funcC). match()" pattern. So in my mind, all I had to do for testing here, was to check, if the flow works as intended.

The bottom layer meanwhile consists of the bread and butter, those nice small pure funcA, funcB and so on. Easy to test... so I thought.

1. Is this architecture a sane approach?

To give you a more visual example of what I did here, let's assume the following original method:

```
public async Task SolveNameAndSendNotification(string id, string note)

{
    string name = await _idToNameResolver.GetName(id);
    await _notification.SendNotificationAsync(new List<string> { id }, name, note);

}
```

This I refactored into:

```
public async Task SolveNameAndSendNotification(string id, string note)
    => await SolveNameAndSendNotificationStatic(id, note, _idToNameResolver.GetName(id), _notification.SendNotificationAsync);

public static Task SolveNameAndSendNotificationStatic(string id, string note, Task<string> nameResolver, Func<List<string>, string[], Task> sender)
    => OptionalAsync(nameResolver)
    .Map(_mapData(id, note))
    .IfSomeAsync(_spreadParams(sender));

internal static Func<string, string, Func<string, (List<string>, string[])>> _mapData
    = (id, note) => name => (new List<string> { id }, new string[] { name, note });

internal static Func<Func<List<string>, string[], Task>, Func<(List<string>, string[]), Task<Unit>>> _spreadParams
    = func => ((List<string> userIds, string[] parameter) tpl) => func(tpl.userIds, tpl.parameter).ToUnit();
```

While it might look like I replaced a rather short method with 4 more complicated ones... this is the *shortest* original method, so while the overhead increased on this one, it decreased significantly for all others.

My problems started when I tried to test the middle and bottom layers. What I didn't anticipate was the difficulties I'd run into trying to mock the bottom layer functions. Following the advice found in "Functional Programming in C#, Second Edition" by Enrico Buonanno, I tried to keep all functions pure and static. As well as to avoid "double testing" the functions of the sut.

So when I designed the tests for the middle layer, I tried to mock all four called functions (nameResolver, sender, _mapData and _spreadParams). Simple for the nameResolver and sender, as all I had to do was to supply a Task-stub. Less simple for the two bottom layer functions, as I had to solve the question how to mock static functions. In the end I chose the approach to change those functions into internal statics, thereby being able to overwrite them temporarily, without compromising security by making them public:

```
var md = Service._mapData;
Mock<Func<string, string, Func<string, (List<string>, string[])>>> mdMock = new();
mdMock.SetReturnsDefault(md(some, noteStub)); // temporary callback to the original function, to be replaced with a true mock
Service._mapData = mdMock.Object;
```

And here I ran into q2-q4:

2. Is it a good idea to only test if the calls are made, or do I need to cover all the branches, thereby significantly reducing the gain from making it functional in the first place?
3. Is there a simpler, more elegant way to achieve the mocking of the bottom layer functions?
4. Some of my bottom layer functions are generic. Now it seems, I can't make those internal, and thereby can't mock them the same way. Is there another way to solve this, than splitting those into strongly-typed non-generic functions?

One of the biggest obstacles for me is also the base structure of the other original methods. In essence they handled the errors in a rather classic way, returning a ServiceResult at every opportunity instead of collecting the validations, and return the final match. I managed to remedy this by using the afformentioned monad.bind structure (mostly language-exts EitherAsync, only rarely the above used Option).

As a result I ended up with a lot of deeply nested functions, often much worse than _spreadParams. Which isn't exactly going to make our customer's developers love my refactoring. And leaves me miffed, as my intention is to improve readability and maintainability. So my final question is:

5. Is there a better way to structure such functions, to avoid having signatures as convoluted (Func<Func<string, Func>, FuncyTown>) as mine?

Comment: I do not see any advantage in this refactoring whatsoever. Unless you can demonstrate its value for a more complex example, I'd say abandon the whole thing, and go back to actually mocking external dependencies only.

Comment: Because let's face it, the type `Func<Func<List<string>, string[], Task>, Func<(List<string>, string[]), Task<Unit>>>` is a **massive** red flag. You have completely abandoned any semblance of readability, for a completely contrived goal of "purity". You haven't even, as you have now found out, gained testability.

Comment: And as a final comment, don't mock pure functions, or higher-order functions.

Comment: *nod* in this case it make things more complicated, true. But looking at the following example:

a function that:

- logs its params
- tries to get a result via an external function
- or catches an error, returning as a service result
- if result null -> return serviceresult with fail
- else map and return the mapped result

In an imperative style I have to test for at least 5 branches:
- failing log
- exception from the call
- null result
- mapping fail
- golden path

What I have in mind tests the flow, trycatch, checkItemFound and mapIt, most of which is reusable.

Comment: And most of the original function are of this kind. Checking some params, making an external call, validating, mapping, return the result. All in one large function.

First I only split it up into simpler smaller functions. But given the basic architecture, this still left me having to test each and every branch. Leaving it a brittle unwieldy husk. Not unit-tests, rather integration tests.

That's why I'm trying this refactoring, to allow for changes being mirrored easily instead of having to rewrite large convoluted integration tests.

Comment: "And as a final comment, don't mock pure functions, or higher-order functions." doesn't that clash with the idea to only test the unit itself, instead of testing the unit, and all dependencies? I thought "mocking" pure functions by simply replacing them with the values they produce would be the correct way. on the other hand ... being pure that difference is probably academic.

Comment: @AndersBernard: Pure functions escape the general mocking advice due to having no state. They are static in nature, which renders them unmockable. As long as the pure functions themselves are tested, their lack of mockability is not considered an issue due to the otherwise high effort and complexity in making such a static method mockable.

Comment: @Flater Thanks, so my basic assumption, that I can avoid having to test every branch of every method at least twice (once for success, x times for each possible fail) is correct, if I replace the branching nodes with (thoroughly tested) pure functions?
That solves MANY problems then.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the tests if you aim for coverage. You can fool tools, sure, but that shouldn't be the goal. If you say these functions mostly follow the "log params, validate params, call external, validate/transform result, return, catch failure", the interesting logic is in those sub-parts. It doesn't do you any good to test a higher-order function implementing the pattern, because it's trivial. You need to test each piece anyway. And I think you're taking the granularity of the "unit" too far.

Comment: What I would focus on more is writing some helpers to reduce the *test code* boilerplate.

Comment: Writing those helpers was step 2 I tried. :D 

The major conundrum I'm facing isn't really the "increase the coverage". If that would have been all, I'd be long done (I had gotten it to 85-90%+ even with the old tests).

The hard part is making it maintainable for our customer. I'm pretty sure they'll add a check here, another log there ... and given the original test style end up just disabling those tests afterwards instead of adding appropriate branch coverages.

Comment: @AndersBernard: No, that is not correct. What you're trying to do relies on knowing that your unit somehow relies on the pure function, but your tests should not know how your unit is implemented. Therefore, your tests (of the unit) remain the same regardless of whether the internal implementation logic of the unit is comprised of pure functions or not.

Comment: My main goal is to have changes by our customer be like: add a new pure function, add a new test for it, click the new function into the flow, add a line to the flow test, done.

Comment: @AndersBernard: Don't take this the wrong way, because it's good to be passionate about something, but you seem to be running with an idea without really taking a step back and objectively considering the cost/benefits here. "It can be done" is not the same as "it is the better choice here", but you seem very eager to jump from the former to the latter when it's about going functional. If what you say is immovably correct, then the logical conclusion would be that everyone who isn't working with functional code is doing it wrong because it would be inefficient. Are you that sure of yourself?

Comment: @Flater ^^, yeah, that's the main reason why I ask this questions here. I'm unsure about that myself, but on the other hand can't really see a good way to achieve the "unbrittle" maintainability without that refactoring either.